# file_get_contents() desont't return all products from a WooCommerce API

Tags: php, wordpress, api, woocommerce

I have the following API url on a WordPress website with WooCommerce:

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/product?filter[posts_per_page]=-1
```

when I visit it in the browser it returns all the products that I need; however
when I try to get the response with file_get_contents it only returns products from a specific category which is extremely strange.

The problem appeared when WooCommerce was updated to the latest version.

Here is the code I use to get the response from the API:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);

$url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/wp-json/wp/v2/product?filter[posts_per_page]=-1';

$data = file_get_contents($url);

die($data);
```

I've been googling and trying different stuff but nothing helped.

I've identified now that the problem is caused by upgrading WordPress to the latest version and not WooCommerce.

Comment: Can you post some code that can help us to debug

Comment: No problem, just added it in : )

Comment: Also, forgot to metion that the problem appeared when WooCommerce was updated to the latest version. It is now in the question.

Comment: I don't know if you seen this, it can be helpful in an other way to do it : https://packagist.org/packages/automattic/woocommerce

Comment: I haven't seen it

Comment: Tell me if it help you